# How do I get the Explosive Tip?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

In **Call of Duty Black Ops** for the **DS**, I see others using an Explosive Tip online. I have unlocked all the weapons except this one, so where or how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to gain access to the hidden Snowman room, which is an Easter egg inside the game.

> The snowman room is located in Weapons Room B in Killhouse, which is unlocked when the achievement "Toys!" is gotten. In room B, one can find what looks like an electric panel by the table with the RPG on it. The electric panel can't be penetrated by gunfire, grenades, or other objects. However, upon closer inspection, the player can walk through the panel and the wall, giving way to the snowman room.
>
> Inside this room, the player will find a frozen pond, surrounded by snow, with a snowman on the pond. Floating and rotating in front of the snowman is the Explosive Tip Crossbow, which can be shot to unlock it for multiplayer use. Upon acquiring the crossbow the demonic announcer from zombie mode is heard laughing. If the player were to return to the room, the crossbow will be gone, though everything else is still there.

[How to access the snowman room - Call of Duty Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Snowman_room)

[Explosive Tip Crossbow - Call of Duty Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Explosive_Tip_Crossbow#Call_of_Duty:_Black_Ops_.28Nintendo_DS.29)